# Git Diff - Get Modified Files Only from the Branch Point

Tags: git, github

I have a use case where I'm writing a Github Actions Workflow to get the modified files in a PR and run lint for those .ts and .js files.

```
- name: Run lint
      run: |
        cp ${{ env.DIR }}/lint-checker/{.prettierignore,.prettierrc} .
        npx eslint --c ${{ env.DIR }}/lint-checker/.eslintrc.js --quiet --no-eslintrc --rulesdir ${{ env.DIR }}/lint-checker/custom-rules $(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=ACM -r ${{ github.event.pull_request.base.sha }}...${{ github.sha }} '*.ts' '*.js')
```

This is what I currently use in the workflow.

The problem is that suppose I create a branch and make a PR, yes I'm getting the modified files and running lint on them. Whereas, if someone else merges their PR to main ( which I branched out from , and has an additional commit now), the workflow runs lint of the modified files in ( my branch + the files from the commit to main )

Can anyone please provide me a solution, where I can get only the modified files only from the point where I branched out from?

I suspect this is because I point to `github.event.pull_request.base.sha` which is different from when I branched out due to the new commit

Comment: Are you actually witnessing the problem you propose, or are you just guessing it could happen? The 3 dot diff you're using should isolate the changes on the right side, even if the base branch changes. It should work the way you have it. (This assumes that `github.sha` is the latest commit on your source branch. If that isn't, then maybe you simply need to use `github.event.pull_request.head.sha` instead...)

Comment: Yeah, I am witnessing this issue. Currently I have to rebase to the target branch to get only the changes in the source branch

Comment: OK. In that case, with 3 dots: `git diff X...Y`, probably your `Y` is wrong. [More info here.](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#example-printing-context-information-to-the-log)

Comment: It looks like `github.sha` might be the temporary merge commit, in that case you could probably do a **2 dot** diff like this: `git diff ${{ github.sha }}^1..${{ github.sha }}`, which should yield the same as the **3 dot** diff against the second parent of the merge commit, like this: `git diff ${{ github.event.pull_request.base.sha }}...${{ github.sha }}^2`

Comment: LMK if either of the options in my last comment work. I suspect that is the answer, and if so I'll write it up.